# Selected options in Multiselect dropdown checkbox not working with DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown, materialize, multi-select

I'm using Materialize Multiselect dropdown checkbox which is used to filter a datatable.
It works just fine when I make the selections.

However when I uncheck all options from a dropdown, the multiselect goes blank instead of showing something like "select options" or "none selected". If I try adding 'disabled' and 'selected' to the first value, the datatable filtering stops working. Here's the JS fiddle, where you can check both the issues - https://jsfiddle.net/ouaprbxy/1/

I have added an extra option 'Filter by Office' in 'Office' Dropdown which is selected and disabled so that we can use it as default value for dropdown. However when you are doing selections, the filering just STOPS in Datatable.

The code in the JS where I'm adding 'selected' and 'disabled' attributes.

`select.append( '<option value="" selected disabled>Filter By Office</option>' );`

However in 'Age' dropdown, if you make selections, it works just fine. But if you unselect all checkboxes, it'll go blank.

So what should I do?  Is there any fix for this issue or an alternate way to show text "none selected" when all filters are unselected? Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With your Age dropdown, you do not have a default value, which is why when you un-select anything it will go to blank.

Comment: Right. But if I add an option that does that like I did in the 'Office' dropdown, then the Filtering stops. So is there an alternate way to show text "none selected" when all filters are unselected?